# Sphinx search complains about missing .sph file for RT index

Tags: sphinx

I added a real-time (RT) index to my sphinx.conf file.  I can see it when I connect to Sphinx with mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3312.  But when I try to do a command-line search, Shinx adds to the end of the response:

`index 'drupal_rt': search error: failed to open /var/lib/sphinx/rt_drupal_nodes.sph: No such file or directory.`

Comment: So can you find this file  "/var/lib/sphinx/rt_drupal_nodes.sph" ?

Comment: Nope.  I don't think it ever gets created.  From an answer I got on another forum, I believe that RT indexes work entirely differently than static indexes.  In addition, they can only be queried with the SQL-like syntax, which the command-line "search" utility does not do.  So typing "search thing" at the command-line on an RT index is futile.

I'm still not a Sphinx export so I'm not going to provide this info as a proper answer yet, but it's based on what I've learned so far along with experience.

Answer (score 1):

./search tool doesn't work with real-time indexes.
You should use mysql client instead.

If you need to use command line search, you need test.php script which you could find in the sphinx source repository under the api dir.

Comment: This is correct. There is a python tool you can use though: `python /usr/share/sphinxsearch/api/test.py some search terms`